# Error compiling CSS asset with Rogue and Middleman

Tags: css, ruby, markdown, middleman

I'm getting

```
'Error compiling CSS asset'
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x007fadea7c9828>::Rogue
```

http://i.gyazo.com/65a0865bc032d5f016c6b99eb24ffd5e.png

I am following the installation guide from the middleman-syntax website.

'stylesheets/highlight.css.erb'

`<%= Rogue::Themes::ThankfulEyes.render(:scope => '.highlight') %>`

'config.rb'

```
set :markdown_engine, :redcarpet
set :markdown, :fenced_code_blocks => true,
    :smartypants => true,
    :tables => true,
    :autolink => true

activate :syntax
```

Completely lost. I cannot find anyone else on the internet with this error =/

Comment: What's Rogue?  <!-- -->

Comment: Rogue is a syntax highlighter built in Ruby. It integrates with redcarpet and this Middleman plugin uses it also. https://github.com/middleman/middleman-syntax

Comment: Did you add `gem "middleman-syntax"` to your `Gemfile` and are you using `bundle exec`?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: No idea then, sorry. You should ask in `middleman-syntax` issue queue.

Comment: Is your project on github? if so can you please post the link, and I'll look into it.

Comment: It is Karim, but I've gone with a different solution because I could never figure this out.